# Python Bar Chart Reordering Y Axis

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I can't seem to re-order the Y axis on my graph. I want it to start with the smallest percent and have the largest on the top. It originally also appears upsidedown so I had to flip it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2xNJ.png)

I tried adding a limit using this line: `plt.ylim(reversed(plt.ylim()))`

Comment: No idea how you managed to do that. You seem to be using a notebook of some sort. Does this issue happen if you restart the kernel, read your data, and use `sns.barplot(...your data here...)` and nothing else?